# How would you save user's profile data from firebase in cache Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, swift5

I have a view controller that is basically the average user's profile on any social media app (showing data like their name, followers, following, name, bio and profile picture). I have successfully made it so all the relevant data get's retrieved from my firebase database.

However, whenever I go out of that view controller and back in again, from the profile screen to a post and back to their profile screen, it reloads all the data again which caused the hard coded values of the profile like 'Name' for the name label to show every time they go out and back into the view controller.

So my question is, how would I retain all the data in a cache - I guess, so it looks like its only loaded the data once (obviously in the background it will check for a change every time you reload the view).

If i'm correct you can solve that problem for string based values (like their name and followers number) by using the firebase offline capabilities? How would I do the same for stuff like their profile picture? Save the picture in a cache and then update it whenever there's a change?

Thanks,

Nathan

EDIT: Here's a video of my problem: [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak51lKFso2vAtuUtDd89SaMIiuokng?e=tdBZkm) as you can see in the video, when you go back out of the view controller, and then back in, the image has to be loaded again. Is there any way to save that imaged to a cache so the next time the profile is opened it will already be there.

Comment: It's hard to be certain without seeing the actual code, but I think you may want to look at [enabling disk persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence).

Comment: This is confusing *it reloads all the data again* - if it were to re-load the data from Firebase then it would always be fresh Firebase data and not default data. Then you state *obviously in the background it will check for a change every time you reload the view* so again, that would indicate the data would always be fresh and never show 'default' data. I don't see any reason to cache anything here since you only want fresh data.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yeah, I've seen that and that solves my issue for things from the database, like their name, but how would I do the same for things like photos (profile picture). Using firebase storage?

Comment: The Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage does not come with built-in caching. But there are many ways to cache them in your own code. See some of these results: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-storage%5D%5Bswift%5D+cache

Comment: @Jay see my edit, there's a video explaining my issue - maybe there's another way around it.

Comment: Well, what you're showing is a viewController being displayed before the data is loaded from Firebase. Load the data from Firebase and then display the viewController within the Firebase closure, that will stop the 'pop' of the data showing up. Secondly, that looks like a tiny amount of data where you could just keep it in memory instead of deallocating it when the view closes.

Comment: @Jay that's a very good point, I can't believe I didn't think of that before hand. Thanks